# i declared a variable in .m file i want to access that variable in another .m file how to do it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i declared a variable in .m file i want to access that variable in another .m file how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make your variable an iVar for some reason then you can declare your variable in 2nd file to have external linkage:

```
// 1.m    
int myInt;

// 2.m    
extern int myInt; // this is the same myInt as in 1.m file
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it an instance variable of the class and you must synthesize the variable.
Then you can access this variable in another class by

```
classObject.variableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .m file:

```
<objectType> *object;
```

In its .h file:

```
extern <objectType> *object;
```

Now just including .h files wherever you need this variable will do.

Caution: If this variable is not of primitive type, you must `retain` this object somewhere. The object must be alive in the program (you can retain it in applicationDelegate to ensure this). Gave me a headache since I thought it would live for the whole program's life.